# Excel (VBA needed?) Select all Cells in a row that have a certain format and are filled, then count them. Use that count in a formula

Tags: vba, excel, cells, region

Analysing some data I got for my company, I need to count cells, so I can work in a formula with that count. 
`CurrentRegion` doesn't work. Here's what criteria need to be met.

The cells counted must be:

- of a certain row (there are other filled cells nearby, which is why CurrentRegion doesn't work).
- of a certain format (mm:ss)
- between 2 cells filled with strings.

This data is collected automatically, so the coordinates of the fields that are filled with strings are not set.

*The (set) row looks like this:*

```
Description  
Description  
...  
Time  
Time  
Time            <- This is the data that I want to count.  
Time  
Time  
...  
Description  
Time  
Time  
...
```

If it was just one of these I might get it, but for me being relatively new to VBA, this is very hard. 
I appreciate every hint. **I don't expect anyone to write the code for me**

Comment: Can you add an short example: a possible case and the expected result ... or something like that in order to illustrate. I admit I didn't get well what you try to achieve

Comment: Example of what you are after would be great. One more, if you are not expecting to write the code for you then what you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

**Only to start ...:**

```
Dim e As Integer

e = 0
For i = 1 To 9999
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then Exit For
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        e = e + 1
        ' Debug.Print Format(Cells(i, 1).Value, "h:m:s")
    Else
        If e <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Count = " & e
        e = 0
    End If
Next
```

the macro print for every section the number of consecutive time values.
The commented Print show the time formatted.
You need to add the code to continue ...
If you want also the Range of rows, modify a little the code:

```
Dim e, i, Addr1 As Integer

e = 0
For i = 1 To 9999
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then Exit For
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        If e = 0 Then Addr1 = i
        e = e + 1
        ' Debug.Print Format(Cells(i, 1).Value, "h:m:s")
    Else
        If e <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Count = " & e & " - Range of Rows: " & Addr1 & " -> " & i - 1
        e = 0
    End If
Next
```